# pattern for regular expression that will eliminate empty string

Tags: javascript, regex, zurb-foundation

I am using zurb foundation and I would like avoid to submit answer consist only with empty spaces.

how can I write pattern that will allow all letters, numbers, spaces and signs (, ; . !) but will not pass empty string f.r `"    "`

this one is ok but works only for one word:

```
<textarea placeholder=""  id="answer-add" required  pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want to avoid is getting a string of spaces, maybe you could use this:

```
<textarea placeholder=""  id="answer-add" required  pattern="^[^\s]*$"></textarea>
```

Comment: Instead of using a negative character class ([^\s]) you can use escaped uppercase S to target all characters but spaces. Also, you probably want to make sure there is at least on character in there, right?
    pattern="^\S+$"